# Adding node in Linked List in a specific position in C

Tags: c, linked-list, trace

I'm trying to add a node to a linked list. The idea is to pass in the pointer, see where new node will go to through a ranked order, in this case G, then D, then M, then S.

Yet, when I compile and run, I'm not actually generating a linked list (this has already been done in the main). I'm more than certain that there's something wrong with my addp() function. Is it that I should pass in double pointers instead?
Sorry for being rather unprofessional and clueless. I'm not the strongest of coders.

Any help would be helpful.

I have attached my method which I have gone through so many times.

```
typedef struct node {
char fname[1024];
char lname[1024];
char pos;
int val;
int rank;
struct node * next;
} player;


    struct node* addp (player* newnode, struct node* list){
    player* templist = list;
        player* templist1;
    // if the list is non empty.
    if (list!=NULL){
        if(newnode->pos == GOALKEEPER){  //insert if G.
            newnode->next = list;
        }
        if(newnode->pos == DEFENDER){// after G bef M.
            // iterate through templist.
            while (templist->next != NULL && (templist->next)->rank < 1) {  // go to end of G.
                // when the list isn't empty next node rank is less than one, keep going
                templist = templist -> next;
            }
            // when finally rank == or > 1, then add newnode.
            templist1 = templist->next;
            templist->next = newnode;
            newnode->next = templist1;
        }
        if(newnode->pos == MIDFIELDER){ //after G and M but before S
            while (templist->next != NULL && (templist->next)->rank <2 && (templist->next)->rank> 2){
                templist = templist -> next;
            }
            // when stopped, then add newnode.
            templist1 = templist->next;
            templist->next = newnode;
            newnode->next = templist1;
        }
        if(newnode->pos == STRIKER){ // at the end.
            while (templist->next != NULL && (templist->next)->rank <3){
                templist = templist -> next;
            }
            templist1 = templist->next;
            templist->next = newnode;
            newnode->next = templist1;
        }
        return list;
        printf("player added");
    }
    // if list is empty
    else{
        newnode->next = list;
        return 0;
    }
}
```

The following is the list function I've come up with. It keeps saying that my linked list is empty. Maybe it's something wrong with this function.

```
int print(struct player* list){
    // create temp list so non modify origin.
    struct player* temp = list;
    if (list == NULL && temp == NULL)
        printf("linked list is empty");
    while (temp != NULL){
        printf("%s \n", temp->lname);
        printf("%s \n", temp->fname);
        printf("%c \n", temp->pos);
        printf("d \n", temp->val);
        temp = temp->next;
    }
return 0;
}
```

Comment: EDIT: I have included the typedef.

Comment: EDIT: I have also included the display function which lists the data in the individual nodes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without knowing the player typedef this is hard to analyze, but I think you can make it much easier on yourself by simplifying the signature of the function to only use player.

```
void addp(player* newnode, player* firstnode)
```

The return is unnecessary since you're just returning the 2nd argument, which the caller already has.  The 2nd argument should be a pointer to a player node, which is the first element in your linked list.  If you can call the function without the compiler complaining about implicitly casting pointers then I don't see anything wrong with your algorithm, although it could certainly be simplified.

Comment: I see that. So it's definetly wise to void the return type. Ok. I've been informed about passing in `player** newnode` and `player** firstnode` instead of my current single pointer. Would that simplify my algorithm drastically as well?

Thanks for the help by the way.

Comment: I don't think you want to pass a double pointer.  That won't really help you here.  The main thing is to make sure you're passing in the address of the first player in the list.  So, when you call the function, if "newnode" and "firstnode" are pointers pass them like this: `addp(newnode, firstnode)` but if they are locals, then pass them like this: `addp(&newnode, &firstnode)`.  Again, the compiler should complain if you mess it up.

Comment: Well, everything seems to work well. Just that when I run my linked-list listing, it shows that nothing is in the linked-list. I will post it and hopefully someone might catch an error in the list function.

Comment: Oh, are you populating your linked list entirely from this function?  If so then that explains the problem.  This function can't update the start of the list.  I would advise just changing the calling function to manually do this, as it is easier, but if you want to use addp to do this then you *should* actually pass a double pointer for the list.  Then dereference it once when you assign it to templist and change the end of the function to `else { list = newnode }`

Comment: I've followed the steps and passed in a double pointer for list. Now the compiler throws a `error: request for member 'lname' in something not a structure or union`

and related errors. 

Sorry for being so confused, and thanks for the help, but how am I supposed to call on these to edit them?

Comment: I think your best bet is to try to open up another question with the changes you've made and link to this question.  It's hard to debug without the code changes.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so what I understood is that your player structure contains a variable pos that will indicate in which place insert the player in the list. Am I right ?

In that case the best thing you can do is to sorted the list by the rank variable. Then modify your pos variable (in the player structure) to match with the rank variable of your list.

Then you will just have to add it with a classic "add in sorted list" function : [C++ Add to linked list in sorted order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4825030/c-add-to-linked-list-in-sorted-order)[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4825030/c-add-to-linked-list-in-sorted-order)

Comment: That's what I'm trying to do there in my code, yes. The problem is that it does not actually modify the list at the end of the day after I run through the method.

Comment: OK so you just have to past the first node of your list by address. As you said in your other comment. But you do'nt have to past the node that you want to add by address. So the function would be like that : void addp (player* newnode, player** list){...}